# asking a Q and get it out of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Q = question

I want to access information from a csv file, for example if the file included:

```
NAME|DATE OF BIRTH|PHONE NUMBER|

 xxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyy| zzzzzzzzzzz|

 xxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyy| zzzzzzzzzzz|

 xxx|yyyyyyyyyyyyy| zzzzzzzzzzz|
```

How would I ask a question, example:

(pseudo code)
what is the name of the person you are looking for? :

And for python to get the information and display it?

Answer (score 1):

Without writing all your code for you...

Break your problem down into the different components you need to implement:

- [Read](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) a [.CSV](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) file
- Organize the data for retrieval (one or more [`dicts`](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), keyed by each field you might want to use to look up records, is probably the simplest solution)
- Get user [input](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) ("ask a question")
- Retrieve the requested data
- [Display](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) the requested data to the user

Figure out (i.e. research) how to implement each of these individually, and then you can write your program to do that. If you then have a specific problem with a specific piece, come back to SO with the code you've written and explain the trouble you're having.

Comment: Yes, but how do i Organize the data for retrieval, that is my main problem as i know how to read a .CSV file                                   Okay thank you

Comment: @user3340683 How have you tried to organize it so far? Think about what fields (e.g. `name`, `date_of_birth`, `phone_number`) you might want to use to look up records. Then you can create dictionaries keyed off these fields, and look up the user input in the appropriate dictionary.

Comment: I am looking to use surname and dob

Comment: Oh so i have now got Organize the data for retrieval but now i need to Retrieve the requested data which i cant find out to do

Comment: @ap306 Assuming you've got a dict called `data` and a requested name called `name`, you just use `data[name]`. Read the tutorial I linked above, or ask another question here on SO with a specific problem.