# Getting information from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a file containing this information ( notepad) :
(if somebody can sort it out please edit)

```
Jackson,Samantha,2 Heather Row,Basingstoke,RG21 3SD,01256 135434,23/04/1973,sam.jackson@hotmail.com
Vickers,Jonathan,18 Saville Gardens,Reading,RG3 5FH,01196 678254,04/02/1965,the_man@btinternet.com
Morris,Sally,The Old Lodge, Hook,RG23 5RD,01256 728443,19/02/1975,smorris@fgh.co.uk
Cobbly,Harry,345 The High Street,Guildford,GU2 4KJ,01458 288763,30/03/1960,harry.cobbly@somewhere.org.uk
Khan,Jasmine,36 Hever Avenue,Edenbridge,TN34 4FG,01569 276524,28/02/1980,jas.khan@hotmail.com
Vickers,Harriet,45 Sage Gardens,Brighton,BN3 2FG,01675 662554,04/04/1968,harriet.vickers@btinternet.com
```

How am I able to ask a question to the user E.G : What do you want to search for and they say name, then I say Enter a Name, how am I able to  extract this information from a csv file and print it?

Comment: no, where can i find it?

Comment: Is the user in front of your computer or looking at your website from afar?

Comment: I'll bet these people are going to be delighted at your breach of the Data Protection Act!

Comment: possible duplicate of [asking a Q and get it out of a csv file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997588/asking-a-q-and-get-it-out-of-a-csv-file)

Comment: these are not real , you do realise that right

Comment: @ap306 Looking up 'python csv module' gave me this link, so it should be enough to get you started http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at that

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding=utf-8

import operator
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("database.csv"), delimiter=",")
```

Once delimited use a for loop to put in variables what you need !

Comment: can you give me an example of the for loop?

Comment: @ap306 You'll have to do some research, especially given that this is homework.